# int produces near correct answer, but float just gives -18.000

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, temperature

I wrote a simple program to convert degrees Fahrenheit to degrees Celsius using functions (been working w/ Python for 2 weeks, wanted to refresh myself):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int temp_change(fahrenheit);

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int fahrenheit;
        printf("Please input a temperature in Fahrenheit.\n");
        scanf("%d", &fahrenheit); //Obtains degrees F value
        printf("%d\n", temp_change(fahrenheit));

    }
}
//Function to change temperature
int temp_change(fahrenheit)
{
    int centigrade;
    centigrade = 5*(fahrenheit - 32)/9; //Changing the temperature
    return centigrade;
}
```

and it gave me correct answers (to the nearest degree). However, I wanted exact answers, so I changed all the `int`s to `float`s (except for `int main()`. Now the only thing the program will give me is `-18.000000`, no matter what input I give it. 
The best way to summarize what I tried: I tried different combinations of the `int`s and the `float`s but with no luck. 
I would suspect that it had something to do with `printf("%d\n", temp_change(fahrenheit));` but it gave me correct answers when everything was `int`, so I don't know. XD
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Very likely you neglected to change the `scanf()` and `printf()` formats when you converted all the data types.  For `float` arguments you want `%f` instead of `%d`.

Comment: Figured it out--needed to initialize the variables inside the function definitions as `float`

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks but no, that would have given me an error.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i am using dev c++, and if i had " neglected to change the scanf() and printf() formats when you converted all the data types" that would have given me an error/warning. what i needed to do was `float temp_change(float fahrenheit)`. See?

Comment: Who knew that using Python for two weeks could have such an effect.

Comment: @JimBalter it was really just solid Python. I was doing an internship, and 85% of the work required it. Fun, but a lot of python lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer version does not give you the nearest converted temperature, it rounds the temperature toward `0`.

There is another problem in your code: the prototype for `temp_change` is incomplete, you forgot to specify the type of the argument.

Here is a corrected version using floats:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float temp_change(float fahrenheit);

int main(void) {
    for (;;) {
        float fahrenheit;
        printf("Please input a temperature in Fahrenheit.\n");
        if (scanf("%f", &fahrenheit) == 1) {//Obtains degrees F value
            printf("%f\n", temp_change(fahrenheit));
        }
    }
}
//Function to change temperature
float temp_change(float fahrenheit) {
    float centigrade;
    centigrade = 5 * (fahrenheit - 32) / 9; //Changing the temperature
    return centigrade;
}
```

Note that you should really be using `double` precision floating point numbers.  Incidentally, the return value of `temp_change()` is converted to `double` when passed to `printf`.  The format specifier `%f` takes a `float*` for `scanf`, but takes a `double` for `printf`.

Comment: thanks very much! i have selected your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the the convert function. Like this

```
float temp_change(fahrenheit)
{
    float centigrade;
    centigrade = 5*(fahrenheit - 32)/9.0; //Changing the temperature
    return centigrade;
}
```

And if you want you can also take the input in float. And here

```
printf("%d\n", temp_change(fahrenheit));
```

use %f not %d

Comment: This is still incorrect: since `fahrenheit` has no type, it is deemed to be `int`.  The expression `5*(fahrenheit - 32)/9` is computed as `int` and converted to `float` when stored to `centigrade`... you get the same result as the `int` version.